# Decompiling .exe files using CodeReflect

Tags: exe, visual-c#-express-2010

I have one silly question that I decided to ask here since Google didn't provide an explanation (or I am using wrong terms, which most likely is the case) and people here have proven to be really helpful before.

Let's say we have 2 different .exe files and I use CodeReflect to view the contents of both files.

1. First file here, it seems quite normal and easy to read. Nothing wrong with this one.

[image: File 1]

2. Second file which makes zero sense to me. I have no idea what's up with this, lots of random characters everywhere. Is this .exe file encrypted or something or why does it look so different? If it's encrypted, is there a simple way to attempt decrypting it?

This one confuses me a lot, I'd really appreciate to get an explanation to this.
[image: File 2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this process is called obfuscation, which is  process to prevent reverse engineering source code. Quit similar like minification in javascript which chooses random names for function and variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **obfuscation**.
It usually helps to fight agains reverse engineers.
You can try to deobfuscate application with this: http://de4dot.com

UPD: And it was probably obfuscated with ConfuserEx v1 because I see 'ConfusedByAtrribute' element.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense now. I really appreciate the link as well.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day!